# find and replace selected text within an HTML/rich text input area

Tags: javascript, html, dom, rich-text-editor, richtext

I have a rich text editor (nicEditor) that stores input in a markup like so:

```
<div
    style="
        color: #bababa;
        background-color: #0c0a08;
        font-family: Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 23px;
        white-space: pre;
    "
>
    <div>
        <span style="color: #bababa"> selectionRange</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">range</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">endContainer</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">innerHTML</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262"> =</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa"> newParent</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">innerHTML;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

the above is the state i can access, but the actual content rendered is as follows:

```
selectionRange.range.endContainer.innerHTML = newParent.innerHTML;
```

i want to be able to select something in the rendered text (say, the second occurance of `innerHTML`) and replace it with something else, what could be the optimal way of achieving this (without using jQuery)? **the key idea is replacing a selection and not just the first occurance of the input**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
foo=function()
    {       
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = `{{C1::${selectedText.textContent}}}`
    selection.deleteContents();
    selection.insertNode(span);
}
```

```html
<div
    style="
        color: #bababa;
        background-color: #0c0a08;
        font-family: Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 23px;
        white-space: pre;
    "
>
    <div>
        <span style="color: #bababa"> selectionRange</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">range</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">endContainer</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">innerHTML</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262"> =</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa"> newParent</span
        ><span style="color: #9d8262">.</span
        ><span style="color: #bababa">innerHTML;</span>
    </div>
</div>



<input type="button" onclick="foo();" value="FOO"/>
```